# Shopify check if image exists

Tags: shopify

I added an image upload setting to my Theme's settings. It's id is `slider.jpg` and I want to know what the liquid function is to check if the image exists. I don't want to show the image if it doesn't exist yet ( Hasn't been uploaded in the theme settings, in admin.

Comment: Where have you uploaded the image?

Comment: Was this ok for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
{% for i in (1..6) %}
  {% assign display_slide = 'display_slide_' | append: forloop.index %}
  {% assign slide_img = 'slider_' | append: forloop.index | append: '.jpg' %}
  {% if settings[display_slide] %}
    <li>{{ slide_img | asset_url }}</li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

and then in your settings file do this for numbers 1 - 6

```
  {
    "type": "checkbox",
    "id": "display_slide_1",
    "label": "Display Slide One?"
  },{
    "type": "image",
    "id": "slider_1.jpg",
    "label": "Slide Image One"
  },
  {
    "type": "checkbox",
    "id": "display_slide_2",
    "label": "Display Slide Two?"
  },{
    "type": "image",
    "id": "slider_2.jpg",
    "label": "Slide Image Two"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using "images" object:

```
{% assign custom_image = images['my-image.jpg'] %}

{% if custom_image %} 

{{ custom_image | image_url: width: 300 | image_tag }}

{% endif %}
```

Ref: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#images

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone trying to check if an image coming from a block or section settings in liquid. Then you can check like this.

For section

```
{% if section.settings.image != nil %}
            <div class="image">
                {{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 400 | 
image_tag }}
            </div>
{% endif %}
```

For block

```
{% if block.settings.image != nil %}
            <div class="image">
                {{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 400 | 
image_tag }}
            </div>
{% endif %}
```